# Write multiple text lines while page is excuting a long running task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write an `asp.net` page, which prints some text as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++)
    {   
        var isOk = DoSomeTask(i);
        context.Response.Write(string.Format("Step {0}: {1}",i, isOk ? "Success": "Error"));
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

I got a problem, the text only shows when the page loads successfully. How can I render text while page is executing?

Answer (score 1):

Well I had read your question quite early in the day but did not answer because I was afraid I may not be able to advise you on solution with concise code sample. You are going to hit same obstacles with both `AJAX` and handlers (`ashx`) and both of these are pretty same.

You have some process doing work on server and you want continues feedback as things are happening on server.

Your best bet is pub-sub model and in asp.net world `SignalR` is the word! Have a look at official resources [`here`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr).

Following are steps:

1. Generate event whenever a part of work you are doing in your long running task
2. setup signalr handler (hub) that responds to the events generated in step 1.
3. in aspx page (client side) connect with signalr hub
4. receive response when event is handled (in step 2) on client side code (setup  in setp 3) and update yuor page.

You can setup signalr handler on server side and subscribe to long running processing task

Comment: Hi, i need monitoring text line which determine current status item. Step 1 is done => show text status, then step 2 is done =>show text... blah blah, like a console app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Response.WriteSubstitution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writesubstitution(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is to do with ASP.NET Page life cycle and Page_load is only fired when page loads successfully. If you are looking for a behavior that outputs text while loading the page, I suggest you consider Ajax instead of ASP.NET default event handlers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Page Load : Perform actions common to all requests, such as setting up a database query. At this point, server controls in the tree are created and initialized, the state is restored, and form controls reflect client-side data. See Handling Inherited Events, it happens after ViewState and PostData is sent into all of your server side controls by ASP.NET controls being created on the page.

Pre Render: Perform any updates before the output is rendered. Any changes made to the state of the control in the prerender phase can be saved, while changes made in the rendering phase are lost. It is the last event you have a chance to handle prior to the page's state being rendered into HTML.

Page Init : is the event fired prior to ViewState and PostData being reinstated.

Comment: Do the same with generic handler ashx without success. I think Ajax can't work without server

Comment: Ajax requires both front end Javascript and backend C# logic to work. It works via javascript calling C# server logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how a web page works, it basically first renders the page in various buffers, then copies the buffers to the client, and then the client buffers everything until it can parse it.

You can actually see what's going on. Instead of using your browser, you can do:

```
telnet localhost 80 (substitute with correct host + port)
GET / HTTP/1.0
[2x enter]
```

Basically the point is that HTTP is not meant to be a streaming protocol in the way you want it to be. So... the way around that is to use AJAX and Javascript.

Unfortunately ASP.Net is also not meant to have background worker processes. The way around that is to use a framework like Hangfire http://hangfire.io/ . Combine that with AJAX callbacks, and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You code is executed on sever side. You need a client side solution. One option is to return a simple page, in the page it uses an ajax call to retrieve data from server side, display a loading animation until the the call finishes.